# Abbreviations of Entschuldigung?

Tags: single-word-request, abbreviation

On a previous visit to Germany, I’m sure I’ve heard (although I may well be very wrong) native Germans using an abbreviation of *Entschuldigung*.

The abbreviation I think I heard was *Schuldi* or something similar sounding to this.

Am I correct?

Do Germans have an abbreviation for the word *Entschuldigung* that’s in the common vernacular?

(and this may well be a region-specific thing).

Comment: Yes, it's an absurdly long way to say "excuse me". When I was learning conversational Yiddish I asked if I could just say "shuldig" but people found that idea comical. We also have a Semitic equivalent though, "sei mir moykhal (lit. "be me forgiving...".

Comment: @MartyGreen: So 4 syllables are absurdly long, but 3 syllables are fine? Do you have an objective measurement to make such assertions?

Comment: Sounds like [a guessing game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/). How should we know what you have heard?

Comment: @userunknown - I don't expect you to know what I heard (and I probably misheard it anyway) but the actual question is not based upon guessing what I heard but to ask if there is a legitimate abbreviation of the word Entschuldigung in common usage.  No guessing required!

Comment: Where in Germany did you hear that!

Comment: I have heard, jokingly, *Schulligung*, but that was not meant seriously anyway. I don't think there is an abbreviation except the increasingly popular *Sorry*, which has been adopted by some people here.

Comment: And it is very well possible that certain groups or subcultures have deleveloped their own abbreviation like "Schulli". But these are very local/personal and not commonplace. Although, sometimes words like "Tschüssi" and later "TSchüssikowksi" spread, even if they are originally not really commonplace.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think what you heard was:

> "Tschuldigung."

I'd say this is the "proper" and only abbreviation. It was used in a title of a newspaper [article](http://www.zeit.de/2003/13/Rempeln_13). 
When I (Berlin) speak in dialect and fast it might contract to something like:

> "Tschu-jung."

"Schuldi" sound very unlikely to me as this would skip the last syllable, which is sort of decisive for the word. *Schuldi* could also be *Schuldiger*, *Schuldige* or *schuldig*.

Comment: In southern regions the leading 'T' may also be ommited to make it sound like *"Schulliung"*.

Comment: Thanks and I wish I could give another +1 for the indication that, in this case, it's the last syllable for this word that is decisive making it far less likely that I heard "Schuldi".

Answer (score 15):

As already mentioned:
`Tschuldigung` seems to be the word you heard.

`Sorry` is also very common,

`Verzeihung` is another possibility. (I'm from South Germany and I wouldn't use it. But I think it is used in other parts Germanys)

In Switzerland you may hear also `éxgüsee` or `Exgüsi` (from the French `excusez`).

Sometimes I heard a 'Pardon` (French pronunciation).

Comment: in bavarian dialect, french words are quite common like "merci", "pardon" but with german pronounciation

Answer (score 7):

It wasn't what you heard, but nowadays it's very common to hear a

> Sorry!

from native Germans - well, we just like anglicisms...

Comment: Indeed... I say sorry all the time

Comment: @Emanuel: Have thought about not doing so much bad, in order to not to have to say "Sorry" all the time? `:)`

Comment: you are right. I am sorry :D

Comment: You might hear "Exekussemie" with the second and third e very audible.

Answer (score 7):

When you want to pass someone who is in your way, say on an escalator, you could say "Entschuldigung", but - in Vienna at least - you can also hear "Gestatten?" ("Do you allow?") or "Darf ich?" ("may I?"), especially from older people.

Also, when spoken quickly in Viennese dialect, it can sound like "tschuigung".

Du "Du"-variation of "Entschuldigung" is "entschuldige", by the way, and it can be abbreviated in speech to "'tschuldige".

I've never heard "Schuldi".

Comment: I think I never heard "gestatten" or "darf ich" in this context here in Germany. But I would understand the meaning, and it sounds quite nice!

Answer (score 2):

I have heard this, near Konstanz.  I think it was some sort of Schwabish-Swiss ultra-local slang, but I've asked loads of German speakers from everywhere else, and they all deny it exists!  I would avoid any abbreviation shorter than Entschuldigung if you want to be understood.

Answer (score 0):

#### The word *Schuldi* exists

and I think it's what you've heard.

I've heard it sometimes in conversations myself, there is also [an entry in *Mundmische*](https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/24299-Schuldi) (the German version of the *Urban Dictionary*).

It's an exclusively colloquial, exceedingly informal and very, very 'cute' (some would say annoying) way to say *Entschuldigung*. Caution: may appear ridiculous if used in an inappropriate context. So it's **not a common abbreviation**.

For other abbreviations see the other answers.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Tschuldi’ was used on tv (Nordic Murders with subtitles on Amazon Prime) between characters playing a married couple being cozy on a sofa
(Follows idea that it’s ‘cute’ or intimate). More like baby-talk than functional colloquialism.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What more reference does one want than movie title and place to watch it?